# What do the permit types in Chicago's Building Permit Data mean?

Tags: documentation, chicago

The documentation for [Chicago's building permit data](https://data.cityofchicago.org/Buildings/Building-Permits/ydr8-5enu) seems to be out date. Anybody know what Permit Type "PERMIT - NEW CONSTRUCTION" and "PERMIT - RENOVATION/ALTERATION" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Those are pretty common terms for building permits.

"New construction" means that they're building (or placing) a new building.

"renovation/alteration" means that there's an existing building that's being modified.

What qualifies as a renovation can get a little interesting by area ... I remember one of my co-workers telling me that in Virginia if you leave one wall standing, you can declare it to be a renovation, and avoid having to pay all of the fees required for new construction if you're looking to tear down an existing building.

See [the city's website](http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en/depts/bldgs/dataset/building_permits.html) for details on the other permit types.